# Monty Hall Problem in Quantum Computing

Tags: programming, simulation

Is it possible to make a quantum [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) where the quantum computer wins the game always?

Comment: Quantum computer cannot see through doors.

Comment: There is this great Medium post that models Monty Hall Problem on Qiskit:

https://medium.com/@sorinalbolos/simulating-the-monty-hall-problem-on-a-quantum-computer-71613f54f0bf

Answer (score 1):

In case you were able to design an oracle for right door identification (I am not sure how to do so), you would apply [Grover algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm)